# how to print source code of a builtin module in python?

Tags: python, ipython, python-module

I want to print the source code of a built-in method.
for example, **math** is a built-in module of python and i want to print the source code of **ceil**

i know how to print the source code of a custom module using **inspect.getsource**

**need help** 
 I am trying to create a programme where i can call any builtin methods or functions and it will display only the source code of that function or module. 
Python has almost everything in builtin library, i  want to use these libraries

example:

```
input: factorial
output:
        def factorial(n):
            if n == 0:        
                return 1      
            else:      
                return n * factorial(n-1)
```

works just fine

```
import inspect
inspect.getsource(factorial)
```

doesn't work ... results in Type Error

```
import inspect
import math
print(inspect.getsource(math.ceil)
```

```
TypeError: <built-in function ceil> is not a module, class, method, function, traceback, frame, or code object
```

thanks in advance :)

Comment: I don't think this is possible. I think most builtins are pretty much compiled C functions with a python interface wrapper. (If you want' to inspect the code, you can always check the repository)

Comment: In `ipython` you can use the `function??` magic to see the source code - if it is written in Python.  But if compiled from C code it will be marked as builtin.  Usually I look online for the development repository (e.g. github) But matching the Python function name with the C function name can be tricky.

Comment: Do you really need to see the source code to use the libraries? But as stated, if you are using CPython, most of hte built-in libraries are implemented in C, and you won't have access to the source. You can find it on the github repo, though.

Comment: On the cpython github, I found  a `math.ceil` in `cpython/Modules/mathmodule.c` that looks like it's the source.

Comment: Download the C source from https://www.python.org/downloads/, then either construct a table of module/source file names, or write the functionality of `grep` to search the C source code.

Comment: `inspect.getsource` will work with any of the standard library modules [written in python](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/master/Lib), of which there are a fair number.

Comment: @cdarke Hi, if you are still around, please consider writing your suggestion as an answer and I will accept it because it will work.

Answer (score 6):

If the source is Python you can do this:

```
import inspect
import math

try:
    print(inspect.getsource(math))
except OSError:
    print("Source not available, possibly a C module.")
```

As other people already commented, many builtin modules are C. If it is the case you will have to dive in the source - fortunately it is not that hard to find, the structure is quite intuitive.

For math.ceil the source code is at [line 1073](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/mathmodule.c#L1073)  of Modules/mathmodule.c in cpython:

```
/*[clinic input]
math.ceil
    x as number: object
    /
Return the ceiling of x as an Integral.
This is the smallest integer >= x.
[clinic start generated code]*/

static PyObject *
math_ceil(PyObject *module, PyObject *number)
/*[clinic end generated code: output=6c3b8a78bc201c67 
input=2725352806399cab]*/
{
    _Py_IDENTIFIER(__ceil__);
    PyObject *method, *result;

    method = _PyObject_LookupSpecial(number, &PyId___ceil__);
    if (method == NULL) {
        if (PyErr_Occurred())
            return NULL;
        return math_1_to_int(number, ceil, 0);
    }
    result = _PyObject_CallNoArg(method);
    Py_DECREF(method);
    return result;
}
```